# Problema con herencia de clases en Java

Tags: java, herencia

Primeramente me disculpo si mi pregunta disgusta a alguien, pero necesito de su apoyo por favor.
Estoy aprendiendo a programar en Java y me tope con un muro llamado Programación Orientada a Objetos, específicamente con la herencia, verán, estoy intentado resolver el siguiente ejercicio, pero no tengo idea de como llevarlo a cabo:

(Utiliza el entorno Netbeans para la creación del proyecto.)

El banco MexBank quiere mejorar la eficiencia del código de su sistema. Se tienen 3 tipos de
cuentas: Tarjetas de Crédito, Tarjetas de Débito y Cuenta de Ahorro. El objetivo es crear una Clase
Cuenta base, de la cual, las demás Clases hereden sus propiedades y métodos.

1. TarjetaCredito
   -private double
   montoActual-
   -TarjetaCredito
   (double apertura)-
   -depositar(double
   cantidad)-
   -sumaInteres(double
   cantidad)-
2. TarjetaDebito
   -private double
   montoActual-
   -TarjetaCredito
   (double apertura)-
   -depositar(double
   cantidad)-
   -retirar(double
   cantidad)-
3. CuentaAhorro
   -private double
   montoActual-
   -TarjetaCredito
   (double apertura)-
   -depositar(double
   cantidad)-
   -invertir(double
   cantidad)-

Requerimientos:
• El proyecto debe de contener: herencia, métodos, uso de variables, uso de modificadores de acceso, paso de variables, encapsulamiento y retorno de valores.

Consideraciones:
• La tarjeta de crédito tiene saldo negativo.
• El método de sumarInterés aumenta el 15% del monto actual a la deuda.
• El método invertir aumenta el 10% al monto actual.
• El método retirar resta la cantidad indicada al monto actual.

Cree 4 clases:

```
package cuentabase;

  public class CuentaBase {

//Atributos
int numero;
double saldo;

public static void main(String[] args) {
   }
}



package cuentabase;

  public class TarjetaCredito {
  }


package cuentabase;

 public class TarjetaDebito {

// Definición de las propiedades de la clase
private int numero;
private double saldo;

public TarjetaDebito(int TarjetaDebito, double inicial) {
    numero = TarjetaDebito;
    saldo = inicial;
} // Fin del constructor cuenta

public void depositar(double cantidad) {
    saldo = saldo + cantidad;
} // Fin del método depositar

public void retirar(double cantidad) {
    saldo = saldo - cantidad;
} // Fin del método retirar

public double saldo() {
    return saldo;
} // Fin del método saldo    
}  

//También considero esto, para esta clase
//Constructor con parámetros
public CuentaBase (int numero, double saldo) {
    this.numero = numero;
    this.saldo = saldo;
}

//Método deposito
public void Deposito (double cantidad) {
    this.saldo = this.saldo + cantidad;
}

//Método retiros
public void Retiro (double cantidad) {
    this.saldo = this.saldo + cantidad;
}//Cual es mejor para el ejercicio?


package cuentabase;

public class CuentaAhorro {

}
```

Y es todo lo que he podido hacer, no se como aplicar los requerimientos y consideraciones enlistados, cabe mencionar que no se si lo poco que llevo es incorrecto o no, por lo que agradecería mucho su apoyo y orientación para este ejercicio.

Saludos.

Comment: Que leiste o trabajaste sobre OOP? porque estas estudiando justamente un lenguaje que es puramente OOP.... Tal vez deberias empezar por leer sobre herencia, o explicar que fue lo que no entendiste de ella...

Comment: Como buena práctica de programación está el buen manejo de la indentación en el código, te ayudará a ti y a los demás a entender el código.

Comment: mas que tener problema con la herencia, es como aplicar el ejercicio, para ser mas claro, ¿Cuáles son los atributos y métodos de las clases?, es lo que no me queda del todo claro para empezar.

Comment: disculpa pudiste resolver el problema?

Comment: Hola si pudiste resolver tu problema?

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres heredar de la clase *CuentaBase* en las clases *TarjetaCredito*, debes hacerlo con `extends` y usar `super()` en el *constructor* de las clases que hereden.

```
public class TarjetaCredito extends CuentaBase{
    TarjetaCredito(){
        super();
    }
}
```

Haciendo esto estarías heredando todos los atributos y métodos de *cuentaBase* a *tarjetaCredito*.